# Fortran Select Type with arrays

Tags: select, fortran

Is it possible to use `Select Type` to distinguish between integer and an integer array? 
I want to create a subroutine where I can pass either an integer or an integer array and
then call the appropriate subroutine.

Comment: You could also try an `interface`... Probably more portable between the different compilers.

Comment: Another related question is how to distinguish between the two.